# Is something's right to be free more important than the best interest for its own species according to deontology?

Tags: ethics

If there were a kind of animal which is endangered, and the only viable way to save this species is to hold these animals in captivity to help them replenish their numbers. Which would be the ethical choice according to deontology, to let the animal go free to not interfere with its rights or to hold it in captivity in the best interests of that species?

Comment: This is assuming animals do have rights, including the right to freedom, which is far from consensual.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-environmental/

Comment: It would rest on what *deontology* has to say about *life* and *captivity*. Clearly, deontology has to copy utilitarianism's stand on *pleasure*. If not we're deadlocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various ethical frameworks such as deontology, consequentialism and virtue are not terms which describe a particular set of attitudes, but are terms which describe *approaches* which may yield a wide variety of attitudes.

Therefore, when you ask, "... which would be *the* ethical choice according to deontology...", you are asking for a definitive answer which cannot be provided.

According to [The Ethics Centre](https://ethics.org.au/ethics-explainer-deontology/):

> *Most deontologists say there are two different kinds of ethical duties, perfect duties and imperfect duties. A perfect duty is inflexible. “Do not kill innocent people” is an example of a perfect duty. You can’t obey it a little bit – either you kill innocent people or you don’t. There’s no middle-ground*
>
> *Imperfect duties do allow for some middle ground. “Learn about the world around you” is an imperfect duty because we can all spend different amounts of time on education and each be fulfilling our obligation. How much we commit to imperfect duties is up to us.*.

So, if you ask:

> "...to let the animal go free to not interfere with its rights or to hold it in captivity in the best interests of that species?"

You are enquiring about an imperfect duty, because the 'interference' of which you speak - including the holding of it in captivity - can occur on a broad spectrum, from trifling interference to almost absolute interference (The same might be said about a vague term such as 'best interests').

You might more specifically define the level of interference as something like:

> The minimum level of interference necessary in order to ensure the survival of the Panda.

Note though that 'survival' alone does not necessarily articulate a desirable quality of life. Do we have a duty to provide this?

Regardless, it is equally valid in the absence of other data or input to claim that there is a duty to not interfere at all with a species which would not ordinarily experience human involvement as it is to claim that there *is* a duty to interfere.

To whose idea of duty do we refer? According to what ideals is our 'duty' arrived at? Where do these ideals come from?

At some point, there needs to be an axiom or assumption of sorts against which to measure our duties or obligations. For example, it might come from a humanistic framework, in which the survival of other species contribute to the broader survival of an ecosystem of which humans are a part. Or, some schools of animal rights might shun the idea of captivity as infringing upon the 'rights' of animals; according to an axiomatic belief that animals should share a similar level of rights as us.

So to answer your question, you might turn it upon yourself and ask yourself what kind of duty we have to the species in question, or you might abdicate responsibility for this decision to duty conceived according to either a liberationist or conservationist perspective.

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a broad-brush answer in the interests of brevity. Most of the historical work on ethics and morals did not consider animal rights at all. Animals were considered to have no moral rights (or duties, for that matter). Deontology takes the view that there are inherent rights and wrongs that can be enshrined in rules, and that you should not infringe those rules just because you have a positive impact in mind as your justification. In that framework, if you had the view that all animals had a right to freedom, you would not consider it proper to infringe those rights in order to perpetuate a species. However, deontology is a framework- it does not in itself provide any definition of the rights of animals, either as individuals or as species.